# How to select multiple dates with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, left-join

I Need to select Data from Tables of a specific user at certain days. I am not exactly sure what is wrong with my code.

Here is my code:

```
select k.info, z.mes_user, z.mes_date, m.val_user, m.val_date
from table_K k
left join table_M m on k.key1 = m.key1
left join table_Z z on m.key1 = z.key1 and m.key2 = z.key2
where (m.val_user like '%Username%' or z.mes_user like '%User-ID%') and
(
z.mes_date like '%18.04.17%' or
z.mes_date like '%20.04.17%' or
m.val_date like '%18.04.17%' or
m.val_date like '%20.04.17%');
```

The mistake is propably in the where clause.

'Username' and 'User-ID' are just placeholders for the code.
 The data type of `mes_date` and `val_date` are date.

Comment: create a variable of Username,User_id and date and used '=' operator

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, move the right side table conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. (As it is now you get regular INNER JOIN result.)

Comment: What is data type of `table_M.mes_date` and `table_Z.val_date` columns?

Comment: We don't know what's wrong either, because you have not shared that information. What output do you get, what do you get, do you have sample data?

Comment: Don't store dates/timestamps in char/varchar columns. Use proper data types!

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: The dbms is Oracle. The data type of mes_date and val_date are date.
Currently it Shows me the values of k.info of every user of the 2 given days. Sorry I cant provide sample date.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: I only want the values of k.info of the one user i type in into %Username% and %User-ID% on the 2 given dates. Not the info of every user in the Database on these 2 days.
Hopefully its a bit clearer now

Answer (score 3):

If the 'mes_date' column's type is `DATE`, you can do the following.

First see how the format of the date is stored in the database table. You can do it by

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(mes_date) FROM table_Z;
```

Then you can create your LIKE condition based on the format.

```
SELECT k.info, z.mes_user, z.mes_date, m.val_user, m.val_date
FROM table_K k
LEFT JOIN table_M m ON k.key1 = m.key1
LEFT JOIN table_Z z ON m.key1 = z.key1 AND m.key2 = z.key2
WHERE (m.val_user LIKE '%Username%' OR z.mes_user LIKE '%User-ID%') AND
(
z.TO_CHAR(mes_date) LIKE '%your_format%' OR
z.TO_CHAR(mes_date) LIKE '%your_format%' OR
z.TO_CHAR(mes_date) LIKE '%your_format%' OR
z.TO_CHAR(mes_date) LIKE '%your_format%');
```

Comment: thank you but I already used the right date format. I just get way too many datasets. i get data sets from all users  in the database at the two given dates. but i only want the data sets from the one user I insert into %Username% and %User-ID%.

Comment: Cool.Glad you sorted it out :)

Comment: `TO_CHAR( date_value )` uses the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the default format model; this is a per-user session setting and should **NOT** be relied on to be consistent and unchanging (especially in international organisations where users in different territories will have different default date formats). Without specifying a format mask the query will break as soon as one user changes their date format and you will have a hard time debugging it as the query will not have changed.

Answer (score 1):

> The data type of `mes_date` and `val_date` are date.

Using `z.mes_date like '%18.04.17%'` is performing a string comparison on the date and effectively the same as:

```
TO_CHAR(
  z.mes_date,
  ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
) like '%18.04.17%'
```

The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is a per-user setting and can be changed by each user. Do **NOT** rely on it to be consistent and unchanging - there lies the road to some very hard to debug bugs where one user changes a setting and suddenly your query breaks without the query changing.

A better solution is:

```
TRUNC( z.mes_date ) IN ( DATE '2017-04-18', DATE '2017-04-20' )
```

But that will prevent you using an index on `z.mes_date` and would require a function-based index on `TRUNC( z.mes_date )`.

You could also use:

```
   ( z.mes_date >= DATE '2017-04-18' AND z.mes_date < DATE '2017-04-18' + 1 )
OR ( z.mes_date >= DATE '2017-04-20' AND z.mes_date < DATE '2017-04-20' + 1 )
```

Which would allow the use of indexes on `mes_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need ( assuming those columns are round dates)

```
select k.info, z.mes_user, z.mes_date, m.val_user, m.val_date
from table_K k
left join table_M m on k.key1 = m.key1 and m.val_user like '%Username%'
left join table_Z z on m.key1 = z.key1 and m.key2 = z.key2
   and z.mes_user like '%User-ID%' 
   and (z.mes_date in (TO_DATE('18.04.17','dd.mm.yy'), TO_DATE('20.04.17','dd.mm.yy')) 
     or z.val_date in (TO_DATE('18.04.17','dd.mm.yy'), TO_DATE('20.04.17','dd.mm.yy')));
```

Comment: This will not work if `mes_date` is `2017-04-18T01:23:45`.

Comment: @MT0 definetly. Added the assumption. Your answer gives the clear perspective for the case the assumption will not hold.